# Add multiple SQLresults to an array while in a foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am having some trouble trying to get this done. The issue is:

I have an array that looks like

> wants_arr_flat 
> ( 
>     [0] => booze 
>     [1] => nudes 
>     [2]
>   => rooms

I want my foreach loop to go through these values making a different SQL statement and then saving the result of that SQL statement on to another array. The code I am trying to work with now is this.

```
    foreach ( $wants_arr_flat as $value ) {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE user_id != $_SESSION[user_id] AND offer='$value'";
      $result=$conn->query($sql);
      $want_match_arr = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($want_match_arr); echo '</pre>';  //testing echo
```

Obviously this is just overwriting the last array each iteration so I only end up with one result in the array.

Comment: If you just need a list of all of the records, try `$want_match_arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result);` (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: Btw I'm not sure you should make ONE request by loop. Try to build multiple query THEN after the foreach loop you make one request and you use `mysqli_next_result()` to get value from one select to the next :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
$want_match_arr = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

use

```
$want_match_arr[] = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: would you mind accepting my answer as the right one? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get multiple rows from SQL then this is better.

```
$want_match_arr = [];
foreach ( $wants_arr_flat as $value ) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE user_id != $_SESSION[user_id] AND offer='$value'";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $want_match_arr[] = $row;
  }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($want_match_arr); echo '</pre>';  //testing echo
```